# Custom markers not clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I had an issue with my custom markers, I want to make it such as a cluster markers (group of makers), but it doesn't work, I found all the markers in the Google Maps, so even I use a clusterManager to handle this situation I can't get the wanted result:

```
    public MyClusterManagerRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap googleMap,
                                ClusterManager<ClusterMarker> clusterManager) {//initialize   
}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterMarker item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {

    imageView.setImageResource(item.getIconPicture());
    Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(item.getTitle());

}

@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<ClusterMarker> cluster,
                                       MarkerOptions markerOptions) {


        iconGenerator.setBackground(null);
        Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster
                .getSize()));
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));

 }

@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
    return false;
}
```

in my GoogleMapsFragment I had this method to draw markers :

> ```
> private void addMapMarkers(List<Place> places){
>
>  if(places != null && !places.isEmpty()  && googleMap != null)
>  {
>          mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<ClusterMarker>(getActivity(), googleMap);
>
>          mClusterManagerRenderer = new MyClusterManagerRenderer(getActivity(),googleMap,mClusterManager);
>          mClusterManager.setRenderer(mClusterManagerRenderer);
>
>      for(Place p: places){
>
>          try{
>
>              ClusterMarker newClusterMarker = null;
>
>              if(p != null)
>              {
>                  newClusterMarker = new ClusterMarker(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(p.getLocation().getLat()),
> ```
>
> Double.parseDouble(p.getLocation().getLng())), p.getName(), snippet,
>   avatar, p );
>                    }
>
> ```
>              if (newClusterMarker != null)
>              {
>                  mClusterManager.addItem(newClusterMarker);
>                  mClusterMarkers.add(newClusterMarker);
>              }
>
>          }catch (NullPointerException e){
>              Log.e(TAG, "7 : "+"addMapMarkers: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
>          }
>
>      }
>
>      mClusterManager.cluster();
>
>      googleMap.moveCamera(prepareCameraForMap(places));
>
>  }
>  else
>      Log.e(TAG, "9 : Markers not drawed googleMap is null"); }
> ```

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: I remove this method :
`shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster)`  from `MyClusterManagerRenderer` then, my code worked fine. Thank's

Comment: Thanks for your update. Glad to hear you resolved your own issue! I suggest accepting your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove this method :
`shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster)`  from `MyClusterManagerRenderer` then, my code worked fine.